# RAID 6 Resync after system crash

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I am running a home NAS server for data storage using linux (ubuntu) and RAID 6 configuration (using MDADM), however, occasionally the server crashes/hangs or experience a power-outage/interruption of power. At this point it has to resync the array after booting back up. My question is, how many drives is it actually resyncing? is it both parities, or just one? In other words, can it tolerate a drive-fail during this rebuild?

/proc/mdstat printout:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid6 dm-3[0] dm-2[1] sdd1[4] sdb1[5]
      5860267648 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [===================>.]  resync = 99.4% (2914697784/2930133824) finish=5.2min speed=49027K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without knowing what /proc/mdstat shows. Note that RAID6 never degrades to RAID0, though.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton added it to the question...